# multiple number of php queries based on js clicks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am fairly new to js. Here I have a js script that adds a text box input on click for queries to a database using php based mysql. Each new added textbox has an id name with a successive number at the end for the number of added text boxes from the js button, like id_0, id_1, etc. I am wondering if its possible to run the php query for each successive textbox individually. The problem I am having is keeping track of how many new text boxes have been added to know how many iterations of the query I should run since the click number is a js variable. Is there a way to iterate a php query based on the number of js clicks, or specifically, a js variable? (or am i think of doing this in the wrong way?)

script to add input box:

```
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" />
<br />
<br />
<div id="TextBoxContainer">
</div>
<br />
<input id="btnGet" type="button" value="Get Values" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var click_number = 0;
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
        var div = $("<div />");
        click_number++;
        console.log(click_number);
        div.html(GetDynamicTextBox("id"+click_number));
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
    });
    $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
        $(this).closest("div").remove();
        click_number--;
        console.log(click_number);
    });
});
function GetDynamicTextBox(value0) {

    return '<label>Input &nbsp;<textarea rows="1" name="id_'+ value0 +'"><?php echo $_POST["id_'+ value0 +'"]; ?></textarea></label>&nbsp;';

}
</script>
```

for the php part, I turn the $_POST variable into a php variable and run a simple query to the database matching the php variable to a specific column. So far I can only do this if I know how many $_POST variables there will be.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this (it may not be the best way), is to have a hidden HTML input which contains the number of textboxes you have created. Each time you add a new text box in JS you increment the value of your hidden input.

Then you can make a loop in PHP to get each POST element.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know how many `$_POST` variables there are if you write the query dynamically. Just be sure that all your POST indexes match up with column names in the table:

For example, if you have:

```
$_POST['name']="bob"
$_POST['age'] = "102"
```

You can dynamically turn that into a query..

```
// First, for security, we should create an array 
// with column names to check against to avoid SQL injection
$tableColumns = array("name", "age", "birthday", "favorite_color");

// This will contain the data that we want to insert
$insertables = array();

// Get the data from the post variables that 
// are named after columns in our table
foreach($_POST as $k->$v) 
    if(in_array($k, $insertables)) 
        $insertables[$k] = $v;

// Create a a query dynamically
// I'm assuming you're using PDO since you didn't specify
$sql = $pod->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($insertables))."`) VALUES (:".implode(", :", array_keys($insertables)).")");

// Execute it
$sql->execute($insertables);
```

Now you can send any POST data you want and if the POST key exists as a column in the table it will be inserted.

Comment: If I make the post indexes match the columns, wouldn't each time I add a text box make the most recent added text box override the previous input from the previous text boxes because they have the same name?

Comment: no, it will just insert a new row for every ajax call. nothing is ever overwritten when you do an "insert" query. inly an "update" query can overwrite things.

Comment: I think i phrased my followup question wrong or might be still confused. In the beginning you set $_POST['name']="bob". If I create 2 input boxes with my js script both with $_POST['name'] as the variable for the input, it'll create 2 identical textareas with the same id and thus only the latter id input will be recognized. Isn't this right?

Comment: yes, if you have two inputs with the same name the last one will be sent and the first ignored, but I thought you were using ajax, which means you don't have to rely on elements names as your pst values.

Comment: ah ok. I'll look into using ajax then and see if I can get your solution to work.